# TCP congestion window equations on slow-start

Tags: networking, tcp, congestion-control

Taking a state driven code from [here](http://cnp3book.info.ucl.ac.be/2nd/html/protocols/congestion.html):

```
# Initialization
cwnd = MSS  # congestion window in bytes
ssthresh= swin # in bytes

# Ack arrival
if tcp.ack > snd.una :  # new ack, no congestion
  if  cwnd < ssthresh :
    # slow-start : increase quickly cwnd
    # double cwnd  every rtt
    cwnd = cwnd + MSS
  else:
    # congestion avoidance : increase slowly cwnd
    # increase cwnd by one mss every rtt
    cwnd = cwnd+ mss*(mss/cwnd)
else: # duplicate or old ack
  if tcp.ack==snd.una:    # duplicate acknowledgement
    dupacks++
    if dupacks==3:
      retransmitsegment(snd.una)
      ssthresh=max(cwnd/2,2*MSS)
      cwnd=ssthresh
  else:    # ack for old segment, ignored
    dupacks=0

Expiration of the retransmission timer:
 send(snd.una)     # retransmit first lost segment
 sshtresh=max(cwnd/2,2*MSS)
 cwnd=MSS
```

There are a few things I do not understand.

1. How is cwnd doubling "exponentially" with "cwnd = cwnd + MSS". I have difficulty understanding how this is an exponential ramp, when its just a linear incrementation.
2. I also do not understand the math behind "cwnd = cwnd+ mss*(mss/cwnd)". The cwnd is supposed to increase linearly, how does this formula achieves this result, when it looks more like a square progression (mss^2/cwnd).

I'm a bit confused with how these calculations perform the described tasks. Could anyone explain how they do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are right, if you execute the formula just one 
cwnd = cwnd + MSS 
this is not exponential

But the key point is: how many times do you execute the code ?
The answer is "at each ack arrival"

So first cwnd = 1 (MSS)

Next time you execute the code you have received 1 ACK (corresponding at the first MSS) so now cwnd = 1+ 1 =2 (MSS) So at this step you send 2 MSS, so you will receive 2 ACKs

So, next time you execute the code twice
cwnd = 2 + 1 =3
cwnd =3 +1 = 4
So at the step 2 cwnd =4 You will send 4 MSS, so you will receive 4 ACKS ans the next time the will be executed 4 times

This is why this is exponential
Hope this will be useful

Dom